# closed form for product of series

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, closed-form, infinite-product

Is there a formula expressing the coefficients of the product
$$\prod_{k=1}^n \left(\sum_{j=0}^\infty (j+1)x^{jk}\right),$$
where $n\ge 1$, in terms of sums of products of integer partitions?

Comment: $\sum_{j\ge 0} (j+1)y^j=(1-y)^{-2}$. Applying this to $y=x^k$, your product is $\prod_{k=1}^n(1-x^k)^{-2}$. This is the square of $\prod_{k=1}^n(1-x^k)^{-1}$, whose coefficients enumerate partitions whose sizes are at most $k$. Since the latter has no closed form, I strongly suspect your more complicated expression does not either. However, it is very hard to give a proof that no closed form exists, so I suspect your question cannot be answered.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Would it be possible to express the coefficient of the product above in terms of products of these number of partitions?

Comment: I think so, but I do not think it is very illuminating. If you edit your question, so it reflects exactly what you want, then I'd be happy to write an answer.

Comment: @AlexanderBurstein. It seems that this reference was given one hour earlier.

Comment: @MikeEarnest, I've edited the question following your comment

Comment: I will give an answer if you edit the question so it addresses my concerns, without referring to the comments.  Also, when you do this, you should be precise about what kind of closed form is allowed. Do you allow sums of products of partition numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$
f_n(x)=\prod_{k=1}^n(1-x^k)^{-1}
$$
It is well known that
$$
f_n(x)=\sum_{j\ge 0} p_{\le n}(j) x^j
$$
where $p_n(j)$ is the number of partitions of $j$ into parts whose sizes are all at most $n$. Equivalently, via conjugation, $p_n(j)$ is the number of partitions of $j$ into parts at most $n$ parts.

Your generating function is
$$
\prod_{k=1}^n \left(\sum_{j=0}^\infty (j+1)x^{jk}\right)=\prod_{k=1}^n(1-x^k)^{-2}=[f_n(x)]^2
$$
Therefore, since the product of generating functions leads to a convolution of coefficient sequences, we conclude
$$
\text{coefficient of $x^m$ in $[f_n(x)]^2$}=p_{\le n}(0)p_{\le n}(m)+p_{\le n}(1)p_{\le n}(m-1)+\dots+p_{\le n}(m)p_{\le n}(0)
$$

Answer (score 2):

Answering the question in title, using Pochhammer symbols
$$f(n)=\prod_{k=1}^n \left(\sum_{j=0}^\infty (j+1)x^{jk}\right)=\frac{1}{\left((x;x)_n\right){}^2}$$

What is interestin if to look at the first terms of the expansions
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 1+2 x+3 x^2+4 x^3+5 x^4+6 x^5+7 x^6+8 x^7+9 x^8+10 x^9+11
   x^{10} \\
 2 & 1+2 x+5 x^2+8 x^3+14 x^4+20 x^5+30 x^6+40 x^7+55 x^8+70 x^9+91
   x^{10}\\
 3 & 1+2 x+5 x^2+10 x^3+18 x^4+30 x^5+49 x^6+74 x^7+110 x^8+158 x^9+221
   x^{10} \\
 4 & 1+2 x+5 x^2+10 x^3+20 x^4+34 x^5+59 x^6+94 x^7+149 x^8+224 x^9+334
   x^{10} \\
 5 & 1+2 x+5 x^2+10 x^3+20 x^4+36 x^5+63 x^6+104 x^7+169 x^8+264 x^9+405
   x^{10} \\
 6 & 1+2 x+5 x^2+10 x^3+20 x^4+36 x^5+65 x^6+108 x^7+179 x^8+284 x^9+445
   x^{10} \\
 7 & 1+2 x+5 x^2+10 x^3+20 x^4+36 x^5+65 x^6+110 x^7+183 x^8+294 x^9+465
   x^{10} \\
 8 & 1+2 x+5 x^2+10 x^3+20 x^4+36 x^5+65 x^6+110 x^7+185 x^8+298 x^9+475
   x^{10}\\
 9 & 1+2 x+5 x^2+10 x^3+20 x^4+36 x^5+65 x^6+110 x^7+185 x^8+300 x^9+479
   x^{10}\\
 10 & 1+2 x+5 x^2+10 x^3+20 x^4+36 x^5+65 x^6+110 x^7+185 x^8+300 x^9+481
   x^{10}\\
 11 & 1+2 x+5 x^2+10 x^3+20 x^4+36 x^5+65 x^6+110 x^7+185 x^8+300 x^9+481
   x^{10}
\end{array}
\right)$$ Finding a closed form of the coefficients of the expansion does not seem easy (at least to me).

Have a look at sequence $A000712$ is $OEIS$ which gives a table of  the number of partitions of $n$ into parts of two kinds. No closed form given but a few asymptotics.

Comment: Yes, my starting point was precisely noting that the coefficients appeared to converge towards A000712, and was curious on whether there was a possible explanation.